# How to restore / recover ESE DB using Microsoft's API

Tags: c++, database, winapi, extensible-storage-engine

What I'm basically trying to achieve here is a proper way to restore a dirty DB.

`esentutl /mh db.dat` yields the following output

[image]

which is fine because i took a copy of the DB while being opened by another program.

is it possible to open the DB using microsoft's JetBlue Api without the proper log & chk files? (*ESEDatabaseView* does it somehow, [nirsoft.net](http://www.nirsoft.net))

If such case isn't possible with Microsoft's API, and logs are needed, what is the correct way of recovering the db(i've changed my DB's & logs location)

here's my code:

```
   wpath p2 = L"C:\\m.db";
        ULONG unPageSize;
        long jet_err = JetGetDatabaseFileInfoW(p2.file_string().c_str(), &unPageSize, sizeof(unPageSize), JET_DbInfoPageSize);
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetSetSystemParameter( NULL, NULL, JET_paramDatabasePageSize, unPageSize, NULL);
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetSetSystemParameter( NULL, NULL, JET_paramRecovery, 0, "Off");
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetSetSystemParameter( NULL, NULL, JET_paramLogFilePath, 0, "C:\\");
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetSetSystemParameter( NULL, NULL, JET_paramSystemPath, 0, "C:\\");
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetSetSystemParameter( NULL, NULL, JET_paramAlternateDatabaseRecoveryPath, 0, "C:\\");
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        JET_INSTANCE instance = { 0 };
        jet_err = JetCreateInstance(&instance, "instance");
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetInit(&instance);
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            JetTerm(instance);
            return false;
        }

        JET_SESID sesid;
        jet_err = JetBeginSession(instance, &sesid, 0, 0);
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            JetTerm(instance);
            return false;
        }

        jet_err = JetAttachDatabaseW( sesid, pathESEDbLocation.file_string().c_str(), JET_bitDbReadOnly);
        if (jet_err != JET_errSuccess) {
            JetEndSession(sesid, 0);
            JetTerm(instance);
            return false;
        }
```

`JetAttachDatabaseW` fails with -550 `JET_errDatabaseDirtyShutdown`

**Edit** I have found out that a simple `esenutl /p data.dat` call without any checkpoint and log files also fixes the issue. I've tried using the `JetExternalRestoreW` command but it keeps throwing `#define JET_errFileNotFound                 -1811 /* File not found */`

```
JET_RSTMAP_W p = {L"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/db/db.dat", L"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/db/db.dat"};
jet_err = JetExternalRestoreW(nullptr, L"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/db/", &p, 1,L"C:/Users/igalk/AppData/Local/Temp/db/",  0, 0, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty shutdown doesn't mean that it's missing the log and check files...  So that might be a separate issue.

You example above has things in the wrong order...

You can configure your application to automatically attempt to clear the "dirty shutdown" by adding the following after JetCreateInstance and before JetInit:

```
Api.JetSetSystemParameter(instance, JET_SESID.Nil, Server2003Param.AlternateDatabaseRecoveryPath, 0, Path.GetDirectoryName(databasePath));
```

(above sample is in C#, but you get the point...)

The last parameter is the location where you'd like the repaired database to appear, so most likely that'd be the same directory as the dirty database file.